# Value does not fall within the range exception in WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, writeablebitmap

I am using WriteableBitmap in my WindowsPhone application to convert UIElement into WriteableBitmap. I am getting Value does not fall within the expected range exception randomly in the following code. But I am not able to find the root cause. Could you please anyone help me on this ?

```
Size imageSize = new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);

WriteableBitmap image = new WriteableBitmap((int)imageSize.Width, (int)imageSize.Height);
image.Render(element, null);
image.Invalidate();
return image;
```

Comment: could you please post your code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WriteableBitmap image = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
image.Render(element, new MatrixTransform());
image.Invalidate();
return image;
```